# How to padding img with dynamic padding inside div with permanently size?

Tags: html, css

I have `div width:200px; height:200px` this div should be permanently size but is it not.
I want to put inside the div img which I can play with padding 10px or 20px each side depend on the configuration of the user .
the img size is bigger then 200px and indeed it.
my problem is when I play with padding the div not be permanently size it changing according the padding.
and I want to separated the padding with size of div.
Thx for any help.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <style type='text/css'>
    img{
width:180px;
height:180px;
margin:20px;        
}

.container{
    background-color:orange;
    padding:100px;
    width:200px;
    hieght:200px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://gfx.glittergraphicsnow.com/albums/ll149/glittergn/flower/flower002.gif" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the [Demo Link:](http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/temp3.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to include the `padding` in the width of an element you need to use `box-sizing:border-box;` on that element.

As mentioned by @bski in the comments and @AshwinSingh's answer - you should also use `overflow: hidden` to hide any overflowing content.

```
.container{
    background-color:orange;
    padding:100px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    /* add this */
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal behaviour is, div takes up the size of its inner contents even if you give it a fixed size. If the total size of inner contents is greater than the div's size, the div will automatically resize to hold the contents. Remember, div is a container, it contains things.

I would recommend using `width:100%` and `height:100%`, to make it resize just enough to hold the content, inclusive of all margins and padding.

If you want to stop that behaviour and use fixed width instead give `overflow:hidden` property, this will hide anything that's overflowing the div. If you want a scrollbar instead give `overflow:scroll` property, this will show a scrollbar when the contents overflow.

**UPDATE** As roger king pointed out, you had `height:200px` misspelled as `hieght:200px`

Comment: Hi, I want  `div with size  width:200px;
    hieght:200px;` I add overflow:hidden property to `.container{` and thats not help you can see here [Demo link](http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/temp3.html)

Comment: Look at your code you have misspelled height:200px as  hieght:200px

Comment: @AshwinSingh it is nothing to do with height, it is because the padding is one the `div` not the image which is why `overflow: hidden` does not work.

Comment: Yes you right but this not solve the problem. you can see the Demo link.

Comment: The div will size according to padding. Padding means how much distance should be between the inner contents and the div border. If you want fixed size of 200px, change padding to 20px.

Comment: @AshwinSingh no, a div by default will size itself to the set width + padding. So if you set padding to `20px` then the over-all width would be `200px + 40px`. What you are refering to would only happen if you added the padding to the child elements